# Unir dos selects en el mismo json sin anidarlos, SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

Tengo estas dos consultas SQL sencillas:

```
--Embarques cerrados
select Nombre,Descripcion from Embarque
where FechaCierre <= getdate() for json path, root('cerrados')

--Embarques abiertos
select Nombre,Descripcion from Embarque
where FechaCierre >= getdate()  for json path, root('abiertos')
```

El caso es que quiero juntarlas en el mismo JSON para no hacer 2 peticiones pero no encuentro la forma, si son anidadas, pero yo quiero una salida JSON de este tipo:

```
[{
  "cerrados": [
    {
      "Nombre": "Luminaria HIGH BAY (UFO) MAY-2020",
      "Descripcion": "Equipos HIGH BAY de última generación de Alta Eficiencia y con sistema de Antideslumbramiento"
    },
    {
      "Nombre": "Proyectores (Floodlights) JUN-2020",
      "Descripcion": "Proyectores con y sin sensor. Cuerpo de aluminio inyectado. Driver con fuente de switching IC. 100% de la potencia nominal. Uso Exterior."
    },
    {
      "Nombre": "Lámparas JUN-2020"
    },
    {
      "Nombre": "Paneles, Tubos y Tortugas SEP-2020",
      "Descripcion": "Paneles 6060. Paneles de embutir y aplicar. Downlight. Tubos. Tortugas."
    }
  ]
},
{
  "abiertos": [
    {
      "Nombre": "Luminaria HIGH BAY (UFO) ENE-2020",
      "Descripcion": "Equipos HIGH BAY de última generación de Alta Eficiencia y con sistema de Antideslumbramiento"
    },
    {
      "Nombre": "Proyectores (Floodlights)  MAR-2020",
      "Descripcion": "Proyectores con y sin sensor. Cuerpo de aluminio inyectado. Driver con fuente de switching IC. 100% de la potencia nominal. Uso Exterior."
    },
    {
      "Nombre": "Lámparas MAR-2020"
    },
    {
      "Nombre": "Paneles, Tubos y Tortugas MAR-2020",
      "Descripcion": "Paneles 6060. Paneles de embutir y aplicar. Downlight. Tubos. Tortugas."
    },
    {
      "Nombre": "Embarque Test"
    }
  ]
}]
```

El resultado lo he juntado yo en un editor de código.

¿Es posible hacer esto en `for json path`?

Comment: usa la clausula UNION

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que necesitas que sean dos objetos diferentes dentro del arreglo y no un solo objeto con dos atributos (cerrados y abiertos)?

Comment: @jachguate si me serviria tener dos arrays (cerrados y abiertos) en 1 solo objeto, pero tampoco se me ocurre como, trate de usar un AND en el where pero no me traia ningun resultado. La verdad crei que era algo comun necesitar hacer una peticion a varia tablas sin relacion entre ellas, incluso a dos db diferentes  y meter todo en el mismo json para no tener que hacer varias peticiones. Yo por ejemplo tambien necesitaria incluir datos de productos destacados que estan dentro de esos embarques, con lo cual necesitaria concatenar 3 queries distintas en un solo json

Comment: Edité mi respuesta para cubrir ese caso.

Comment: tu respuesta es correcta como lo era la primera, el caso es que no puedo o no se como asignar toda la query a una variable, o sea, declaro la variable, la asigno y hago el select de ma variable y marca error. En la respuesta de @Marcos si pude asignar toda la query a una variable. Esto lo necesito por el tema de limitacion de caracteres que tiene sql server para json de consultas directas, no se porque sucede, pero al asignar la query a una variable no se corta el json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma de lograrlo (*seguramente no es la mejor*) puede ser así:

- Cada consulta con `for json path` devuelve una cadena de texto.
- Si hacemos un `UNION` con ambas vamos a obtener 2 registros
- Para unir ambos registros (*el JSON con `{"cerrados":[...]}` y `{"abiertos":[...]}`*) podemos usar [`STRING_AGG()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- Finalmente con [`CONCAT()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) agregamos los corchetes al inicio y al final

#### Ejemplo:

```
SELECT CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(T.json, ',') ,']') AS json
FROM (
  SELECT (
    select Nombre, Descripcion from Embarque
    where FechaCierre <= getdate() for json path, root('cerrados')
  ) AS json
  UNION ALL
  SELECT (
    select Nombre, Descripcion from Embarque
    where FechaCierre >= getdate() for json path, root('abiertos')
  ) AS json
) T
```

**Resultado:**

```
[{"cerrados":[...]},{"abiertos":[...]}]
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c62875376609448247144c1f81669a2b)</kbd>

---

Para lograr que `abiertos` y `cerrados` sean propiedades de un mismo objeto podemos hacerlo así:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT Nombre, Descripcion from Embarque
   where FechaCierre <= getdate() for json path) cerrados,
  (SELECT Nombre, Descripcion from Embarque
   where FechaCierre >= getdate() for json path) abiertos
for json path, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

**Resultado:**

```
{"cerrados":[...],"abiertos":[...]}
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3360a81a5db960e1c3d9721b7ed2e68e)</kbd>

Comment: las dos opciones me han servido, pero con esta pude asignar toda la consulta a una variable. Ahora, podria hacerse todo en un mismo objeto? Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: si bien anda de la manera que me plantearon, como decia en su comentario @jachguate, lo suyo seria un solo objeto con dos propiedades, abiertos y cerrados. De esta manera seria mas eficiente o de buena practica, no se como decirlo. Puedo editar mi pregunta y agregar el nuevo json si quieres.

Comment: lo tendria listo si pudiese usar root en conjunto con WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER

Comment: @HernánGarcia, he actualizado mi respuesta. Dejame saber si es lo que estabas buscando

Comment: impecable @Marcos, me ha sido muy util, muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo en responderme, saludos!!

Answer (score 2):

Si realmente necesitas dos objetos en el arreglo final, creo que la única manera es *armar* el arreglo a mano, por ejemplo:

```
with
cerrados (jsn) as (
select Nombre, Descripcion 
  from Embarque
 where FechaCierre <= getdate() for json path, root('cerrados')
)
,
abiertos (jsn) as (
select Nombre, Descripcion 
  from Embarque
 where FechaCierre >= getdate()  for json path, root('abiertos')
)
select '[' + cerrados.jsn + ', ' + abiertos.jsn + ']'
  from cerrados, abiertos
```

Si quieres ambas respuestas en un único objeto, con los atributos `cerrados` y `abiertos`, puedes utilizar este otro query:

```
with
cerrados (cerrados) as (
select Nombre, Descripcion 
  from Embarque
 where FechaCierre <= getdate() for json path
)
,
abiertos (abiertos) as (
select Nombre, Descripcion 
  from Embarque
 where FechaCierre >= getdate()  for json path
)
select *
  from cerrados, abiertos
   for json path;
```

Esto va a dejar un resultado como el siguiente:

```
[
   {
      "cerrados":[
         {
            "Nombre":"Embarque1",
            "Descripcion":"Embarque 1"
         },
         {
            "Nombre":"Embarque2",
            "Descripcion":"Embarque 2"
         }
      ],
      "abiertos":[
         {
            "Nombre":"Embarque6",
            "Descripcion":"Embarque 6"
         },
         {
            "Nombre":"Embarque7",
            "Descripcion":"Embarque 7"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Gracias @Marcos, se me coló una consulta distinta a la que debí pegar, ya está actualizada la respuesta.